# List of WCAG 2.0 AA Guidelines that Achecker covers

Tags: web, accessibility, wcag2.0

I am looking for list of WCAG 2.0 AA Guidelines that Achecker ([achecker.ca](http://achecker.ca/)) covers (which is part of our automation) to make sure we don't have to cover those in our manual testing.

I couldn't find those details in their website. Any help to find the already covered guidelines by achecker is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean http://achecker.ca/?

Comment: Yes Unor. It is achecker.ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, here are the guidelines and techniques covered by "achecker".

- 1.1.1 **Non-text Content (A)**  H24,G73,H37,H36,H67,H35,H53,H46,F38,H45,G94,G72,H52
- 1.2.7 **Extended Audio Description ...**    G69,G58
- 1.3.1 **Info and Relationships (A)**    H44,H71,H42,H39,F46,H43,H34,H73,H63,H51,H56
- 1.3.2 **Meaningful Sequence (A)**   G111
- 1.3.3 **Sensory Characteristics (A)**   F49
- 1.4.1 **Use of Color (A)**  H21,G18,F24
- 1.4.3 **Contrast (Minimum) (AA)**   G17,H21
- 2.1.1 **Keyboard (A)**  SCR20,G21
- 2.2.1 **Timing Adjustable (A)** F40
- 2.2.2 **Pause, Stop, Hide (A)** F47
- 2.3.1 **Three Flashes or Below Thre...**    G15
- 2.4.1 **Bypass Blocks (A)** H69,H64,G1,H70,H50
- 2.4.3 **Focus Order (A)**   H25
- 2.4.4 **Link Purpose (In Context) (...**    H30
- 2.4.5 **Multiple Ways (AA)**    G131
- 2.4.6  **Headings and Labels (AA)** H4
- 2.4.7 **Focus Visible (AA)**    G65,H59
- 3.1.1 **Language of Page (A)**  H55,H57
- 3.1.2 **Language of Parts (A)** H58
- 3.1.2 **Language of Parts (AA)**    H58
- 3.2.1 **On Focus (A)**  F52
- 3.2.2 **On Input (A)**  G107
- 3.2.3 **Consistent Navigation (AA)**    G61

This does not mean that you don't have to care about those different points in your manual testing.

Note: this was extracted from an ["achecker.ca" installation](http://www.atutor.ca/achecker/) with the following SQL request:

```
SELECT ags.subgroup_id,CAST(lt.text AS CHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8) title,
      group_concat(distinct technique) techniques
FROM AC_guideline_subgroups ags 
      JOIN AC_language_text lt on ags.name=lt.term
      JOIN AC_techniques at ON at.subgroup_id=ags.subgroup_id
GROUP BY ags.subgroup_id
ORDER BY title;
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, What I meant is we are automating the achecker test for all our pages.

Comment: Thanks Adam, modified my question accordingly. can you please provide any references for the above answer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I added a note to provide the source